# Using TLS/SSL Client Authentication for specific hosts

Tags: go, ssl, reverse-proxy, client-certificates, httprouter

How can I use TLS/SSL Client Authentication for specific Hosts when using a reverse proxy like [httprouter by julienschmidt](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter?tab=doc)?

I could set a Client Certificate in a global matter with `http.DefaultTransport`.

```
transport := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    },
}

http.DefaultTransport = transport
```

But want to use Client Certificate only for **specific hosts**, like:

1. cert1 for host1
2. cert2 for host2
3. everything else with **no** Client Certificate

#### Update

I expected that the callback `GetConfigForClientHandler` or
`GetCertificateHandler` would be called. At this point I could react on the `info.ServerName`. But only `GetClientCertificate` get called with no information about the target `info.ServerName`.

```
func main() {
    transport := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            GetConfigForClient:   GetConfigForClientHandler,
            GetClientCertificate: GetClientCertificateHandler,
            GetCertificate:       GetCertificateHandler,
        },
    }

    http.DefaultTransport = transport

    // Host which enforce client certificate authentication
    resp, err := http.Get("https://example.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}

func GetClientCertificateHandler(info *tls.CertificateRequestInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
    fmt.Println("GetClientCertificateHandler")
    panic("GetClientCertificateHandler")
}

func GetConfigForClientHandler(info *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Config, error) {
    fmt.Println("GetConfigForClientHandler for:", info.ServerName)
    panic("GetConfigForClientHandler")
}

func GetCertificateHandler(info *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
    fmt.Println("GetCertificateHandler for:", info.ServerName)
    panic("GetCertificateHandler")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a TLS config which is shared for all hosts. Probably you don't need to set much there. But you want to set a [`Config.GetConfigForClient`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config.GetConfigForClient) handler.
2. In that handler, you check the [`ClientHelloInfo.ServerName`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ClientHelloInfo). That is the requested host. You then modify the TLS config to require client auth there ([`Config.ClientAuth`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config.ClientAuth)).
3. Wrap your net.Listener with [`tls.NewListener`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#NewListener)
4. Use your TLS `net.Listener` in [`http.Serve`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve) (here is where you could then use httprouter)

Comment: I have some trouble to understand step 3 and 4, why do I need a Listner when I want to atach a certificate to a client.
Maybe it is easier to use the `http.DefaultTransport`, where I set the client certificate in the first place. But if I set in `http.DefaultTransport` the func for `Config.GetConfigForClient`, it wasn't called, either was `Config.GetClientCertificate`, only `Config.GetCertificate`get called, but in this func I don't have any information about the `ServerName`.